# Qlikview: Build Logic/KPI to Count distinct devices using Loops/Set Analysis

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

Please help me building logic on below scenario.

I have a data, in which there are many device saying A/B/C.., with their server up/down status being 1/0 respectively and dates(24 Hour) corresponding to it.

What I want here is to Count No. of distinct devices in a dataset, which are UP in entire day for atleast once. Means, If any device is Up i.e 1  for atleast once in a day, then it is counted as 1, and check for other devices and count the others similarly.  and finally show the total UP devices Reported. Vice Versa for the devices which were Down whole day.

I am sorry, if I am putting this again, But I didn't find any post regarding this.

I am not sure which function/loop will give the correct logic? Can we do it through loop, or set analysis can do this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple I'm set analysis. Something like
`count({<Status={1}>}distinct DeviceID)` to get all machines that have been up at all. 
There's probably a clever way to do the down all day but I can't think of it other than
`count(distinct DeviceID)-count({<Status={1}>}distinct DeviceID)`

Comment: Total No of Ups and down count doesnt matches with the total no of UP devices, and down devices through this way.